# An unhandled exception occurred: Schematic "appShell" not found in collection "@ionic/angular-toolkit"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

## Problem

The following error occurs when invoking command `ng generate`:

> An unhandled exception occurred: Schematic "appShell" not found in collection "@ionic/angular-toolkit".

Answer (score 14):

You're using the wrong command. When working with *Ionic v4*, you **must** use *Ionic* commands.

Use instead `ionic generate`.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you have the default schematics set to ionic (@ionic/angular-toolkit) in angular.json. This is defined by [schematicCollections](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#angular-cli-configuration-options) near the bottom:

```
  "cli": {
    "analytics": true,
    "schematicCollections": ["@ionic/angular-toolkit"]
  },
```

By simply removing this line, the angular schematics will work again, but the ionic schematics won't.

```
  "cli": {
    "analytics": true
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference you can also add the angular schematics, like so:

```
"cli": {
  "schematicCollections": [
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit",
    "@schematics/angular"
  ],
  "analytics": false
},
```

Use with care.